# jQuery/PHP-MySQL News Ticker

Tags: php, mysql, slider, news-ticker

I have been searching for a Vertical Text Slider OR Vertical News Ticker, exactly like this one:
http://www.tradekey.com/
(scrolling the latest buy/sell offers in the middle)

I found few tickers but I still can't figure out how do I make it to get data from one specific MySQL table & display them randomly.

Someone point me to right direction or provide me any link where I can found any easy to configure news ticker.

UPDATE-171212:
Well I checked the ajax folder, there are some files getting user info from db.
But it always displays the country info from the member profile, by ignoring what is mentioned in the "buying/selling lead" info.
its using $country, & its same in both member profile info table & buying/selling leads table.
What if I want it to pick from buy/sell leads, & if no country is mentioned then get country data from member profile.
For Example:
http://www.tradeglobus.com (import export trade leads in the middle)
I have to correct country info issue in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `setInterval` mixed with `AJAX` to update a list of the items you want to display. Then look into `Jquery` to add a ticker effect.

---

To elaborate, create a file that fetches the items from a DB. Then use an ajax request to get that list at regular intervals. From there it just takes a Jquery plugin or equivalent to display the list in `ticker` form